# MYSQL + PHP trying to insert IPA characters

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, ipa, utf

I'm having an issue inserting phonetic pronunciations into my database. Here's some images showing what I've done, and the result at the end.

Here's my table layout :

[image]

I've added the header on the file that I'm running the script on :

[image]

On the web page, the encoding is fine :

[image]

Here's how it's uploaded into the database :

[image]

Thanks guys please give me some insight on what I'm doing wrong. I'm using phpmyadmin, and on the column for the ipa I'm using ***utf8mb4_bin***

Comment: What is the problem is the encoding is fine ?

Comment: The result is : nÃ¼-mÉ™-nÉ™s, which is not the correct IPA that I entered

Comment: No the result is good on your website, but the visualisation of your data is just not in UTF8

Comment: Please don't post code as images

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it myself, because I'm using PDO I simply added **charset=utf8** to the connection string

```
$DB = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8",$user,$pass);
```

Comment: Yes always make sure your DB connection, physical files and encoding of the output are the same

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure that the connector is also set to utf8mb4:

e.g. `$this->con->set_charset("utf8mb4");`

But most of your answers should be [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)